# How to delete all elements from list A which are also in list B?

Tags: c, arrays, removeall

I'm looking for a removeAll equivalent for C.

I'll clarify my question with a simple example.

I have a list of structs type Element.

```
Element** list1 = {A, B, C, D, E F}
```

There is also a second list

```
Element** list2 = {B, E}
```

Now I want to delete all elements from list1 which are also contained in list2.
I also want my list1 to be reallocated.

The resulting list contains elements {A, C, D, F}.

The used datastructure has to be an array since I want to look up elements on index very fast.

I had developed a solution myself. Unfortunately I needed too much loops.

Comment: You know how to delete from a list? So you loop into `list2` and ask to delete the elements from `list1`.

Comment: Please give a fuller code example to show what `A, B, ..` mean, and why you use a double `**`. *"I had developed a solution myself"* was the problem "too many loops" or not working? Please post some proper code that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can gave you n*log(n) solution, but this requires the objects are sortable.

1. sort the two list of object. //n*log(n)
2. go through list B, if elements B[i] existed in list A, remove it, this could be done in one loop.
3. If you want keep the origin order of list A, you need remove the matched items from origin list A directly.

Comment: The order in list A can indeed not be disturbed. In step 2 I assume you shift the remaining elements  on the go and realloc once at the end?